# Trying To Setup a Rails 5 App With Apache and Passenger on CentOS 6.8

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, webserver, ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm quite new, so this is what I've done:

I worked on my Rails app, which works fine if I run it with `rails s` command, but I want to access to my app from other devices in my Lan (or even when I'm outside my home), the apache server is """running""" using an old Notebook that I have running `24/7` which I already use as a `ssh` server, so I followed this guide: http://www.rabblemedia.net/blog/installing-rvm-ruby-on-rails-and-passenger-on-centos-6/

I don't know if I've done something wrong, according to me I just did the same as what's in the guide, but when I try to access to my web app from another device trough the IP of my CentOS I only get `Err_Connection_Timed_Out`, I don't know what info should I put so I will put what I think is important:

- **The local IP of my CentOS is `192.168.0.53`**
- **The hostname is: `vmcentos`**
- **The route to my app is `/var/www/calendar`**
- **`service httpd status` returns: `httpd (pid  1196) is running...`**

Apart from that:

**The `/etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf` file has this content:**

```
        PassengerRoot /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@calendar/gems/passenger-5.0.30
        PassengerDefaultRuby /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@calendar/wrappers/ruby
</IfModule>
### End automatically installed Phusion Passenger config snippet ###

# Deploying a web application: an example

# Suppose you have a web application in /somewhere. Add a virtual host to
# your Apache configuration file and set its DocumentRoot to /somewhere/public:
#
#    <VirtualHost *:80>
#       ServerName www.yourhost.com
#       # Be sure to point to 'public'!
#       DocumentRoot /somewhere/public
#       <Directory /somewhere/public>
#          # Relax Apache security settings
#          AllowOverride all
#          # MultiViews must be turned off
#          Options -MultiViews
#       </Directory>
#    </VirtualHost>
```

**The configuration file for my project is in this route and file `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/calendar.conf` and has this content:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName vmcentos
        DocumentRoot /var/www/calendar/public
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/calendar/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/calendar/access.log common

        <Directory /var/www/calendar/public>
                AllowOverride all
                Options -MultiViews
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**At the end of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` I added:**

```
Include sites-enabled/*.conf
```

- **`netstat -tulpn | less` returns:**

[image]

- **`passenger-status` returns:**

[image]

**I'm not sure what could be the problem, but my app is not being loaded, any kind of help or commentary is welcome!!!**

Answer (score 0):

sorry for being not fully into this, i started learning ruby recently.
but shouldn't the document root be the root of the project, and the directory point to the public?
 like

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/calendar/

 <Directory /var/www/calendar/public>
            AllowOverride all
            Options -MultiViews
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

i found this config on another website, using passenger and apache2 on ubuntu/debian systems

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /home/rails/testapp/public
RailsEnv development
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory "/home/rails/testapp/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: for if this answer didnt fully work, i found this website on how to set it up on centos6: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6

Comment: Every tutorial, website or reference I've saw show that `DocumentRoot` point to the public directory instead of the root of the project. You can see that in the last config you put.

Comment: Ye i know though my feeling says the document root should't be in public. Well, i hope you have found an answer or that the link had some usefull information

Comment: Yeah, I followed that tutorial (and a couple more too), but I can't make it work, thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh and about the timeout error, as you are in vm. What are the vm lan settings?